# Can't delete the HATBM relationship in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Not sure how to delete the associate between 'fly' and 'invoice'. What I've tried so far deletes the fly from the database

```
<table class="table table-condensed">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Invoice Flies</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <% @invoice.flies.each do |fly| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= fly.name %></td>
          <td><%= link_to "delete", ??????, method: :delete,
                                  data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %></td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Invoice Model:

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :active
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :flies, through: :categorizations
end
```

Invoice migration:

```
class CreateInvoices < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :invoices do |t|
      t.boolean :active
      t.integer :user_id

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :invoices, :user_id
  end

end
```

Categorization Model:

```
class Categorization < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :fly_id, :user_id

  belongs_to :invoice
  belongs_to :fly
end
```

Categorization migration:

```
class CreateCategorizations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :categorizations do |t|
      t.integer :user_id
      t.integer :fly_id

      t.timestamps

      add_index :categorizations, :user_id
      add_index :categorizations, :fly_id
    end
  end
end
```

Fly Model:

```
class Fly < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :name
  validates :description, :name, presence: true

  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :invoices, through: :categorizations
end
```

Fly migration:

```
class CreateFlies < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :flies do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :description

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: We need the code models `fly` and `invoice`

Comment: I've now added the models to the question.

Comment: jrturner1234 what happened to this? did `dependent: destroy` not solve the issue you were having?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dependent: :destroy` like this:

```
class Fly
  has_many :categorizations, dependent: :destroy
  ...
end
```

This will destroy the categorizations related to that `Fly`.

Also, remember to use `Fly.destroy(:id)` (DO NOT USE `Fly.delete(:id)`, or it won't remove the categorizations dependent on that `Fly`)